# Ubuntu boots immediately in my dual-boot system

Tags: dual-boot

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer. When I restart I do not have the option to go to either Windows or Ubuntu. I get a black screen with this text in the top left corner:

```
7.691547 KVM: disabled by bios.
```

Then Ubuntu boots up...

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed it beside my existing operating system and letting the default installation settings do the job.

How can I have the option to choose between operating systems when I reboot or turn on my computer?

Comment: How exactly did you installed ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Which option did you choose when during the installation you were asked about the installation type? One of the options is to erase the disk and install Ubuntu, another one (the one you should choose) asks whether you want to install next to Windows.

If you chose the correct installation type, can you check if you can see the Windows partitions in Nautilus (the file explorer)?

Alternatively, you can open a terminal window (hit the Windows key and type 'terminal'), then run the following command to show us the partition layout of your harddisk (if you have more than one harddisk, let us know):

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

This will ask you for your password and then show which partitions are present on your harddisk. Please past that output here.

Answer (score -1):

If you are about to Erase disk, then first install Windows and then Go for Wubi, as a newbie it will help you to install Ubuntu as its GUI and easy to use. If you want to install Ubuntu using Disk then first check your partitions for Ubuntu using GParted, You can find it by hitting Window key and type Gparted in Ubuntu. It will help you to install Ubuntu properly